# How to configure time zone in Testcontainers MySQL

Tags: testcontainers

May I know how do we configure the time zone in Testcontainers MySQL during testing? Also, how can we verify the time zone in Testcontainers MySQL?

Comment: Can you tell which parts of this document are unclear: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html ?

Comment: See the link [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mysql/) to configure the time zone in Testcontainers MYSQL module. We can define the time zone in my.cnf as one of our test resources, and tell Testcontainers to load it via the URL, e.g. "jdbc:tc:mysql:5.7.34://hostname/databasename?TC_MY_CNF=somepath/mysql_conf_override".

Answer (score 1):

You may use the jdbc connection string to make the MySQL testcontainer use your "cnf" file, which sets the timezone

```
jdbc:tc:mysql:5.7.34://hostname/databasename?TC_MY_CNF=mysql_conf_override
```

And under **mysql_conf_override** folder you need to have a **my.cnf** file with the following content:

```
[mysqld]
default-time-zone = "Europe/Istanbul"
```

Finally, you may check the TZ in your testcontainer via

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;
```

after connecting to the container:

```
mysql -u root -ptest
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add an init script setting the timezone:

```java
new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0.32").withInitScript("init.sql");
```

Then you add to your `init.sql` file the following command:

```sql
-- Here you can put other SQL commands

SET time_zone =  'UTC';
```