# Jhipster 7.9.3 generated project with test database mysql (same as prod), the HibernateTimeZoneIT tests fails

Tags: jhipster

I created a simple JHipster project through the command line,

```
jhipster
```

and selected the dev database to be set to "mysql", which uses testcontainers to run the integration tests.

I added no entities of my own, but when running `./mvnw clean verify`, the HibernateTimeZoneIT tests throws the following error

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeInstantWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnGMTTimeZone:66->assertThatDateStoredValueIsEqualToInsertDateValueOnGMTTimeZone:159
expected: "2014-11-12 05:50:00.0"
 but was: "2014-11-12 06:50:00.0"
[ERROR]   HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeLocalDateTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnGMTTimeZone:78->assertThatDateStoredValueIsEqualToInsertDateValueOnGMTTimeZone:159
expected: "2014-11-12 06:50:00.0"
 but was: "2014-11-12 07:50:00.0"
[ERROR]   HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeOffsetDateTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnGMTTimeZone:90->assertThatDateStoredValueIsEqualToInsertDateValueOnGMTTimeZone:159
expected: "2011-12-14 08:30:00.0"
 but was: "2011-12-14 09:30:00.0"
[ERROR]   HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeZoneDateTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnGMTTimeZone:102->assertThatDateStoredValueIsEqualToInsertDateValueOnGMTTimeZone:159
expected: "2011-12-14 08:30:00.0"
 but was: "2011-12-14 09:30:00.0"
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 90, Failures: 4, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Created the sample project with the following configurations

```
Welcome to JHipster v7.9.3

Application files will be generated in folder: C:\Users\Midhu Moyalan\Workspaces\JHipsterWorkspace\sampleProject
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Documentation for creating an application is at https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/
  If you find JHipster useful, consider sponsoring the project at https://opencollective.com/generator-jhipster
 _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________

? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)
? What is the base name of your application? sampleProject
? Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? No
? What is your default Java package name? com.mycompany.myapp
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which cache do you want to use? (Spring cache abstraction) Ehcache (local cache, for a single node)
? Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No
? Which other technologies would you like to use?
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? Angular
? Do you want to generate the admin UI? Yes
? Would you like to use a Bootswatch theme (https://bootswatch.com/)? Default JHipster
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
? Please choose the native language of the application English
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use?
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No
Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 99,999 days
        for: CN=Java Hipster, OU=Development, O=com.mycompany.myapp, L=, ST=, C=
```

I have not added any additional testing frameworks.

This is my java version

```
$ java --version
java 17.0.2 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have a **mysql:8.0.30** image download in my docker images.

I did not see any error while the project was created. Is there something else to be configured when a project is created  with MYSQl database for the dev environment? I would prefer to use testcontainers...

---

**Trials 1#**
I add the following in the "my.cnf" file
`default-time-zone = "UTC"`

[Image from the MysqlTestContainer.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJN4V.png)

But the value does not seems to be taken into consideration.

---

**Trial 2#**
I added the init.sql file with the content
`SET time_zone =  'UTC';` and included this file with the .withInitScript as shown below, but the integration tests still fails

```
 @Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    if (null == mysqlContainer) {
        mysqlContainer =
            new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0.30-debian")
                .withDatabaseName("sampleProject")
                .withTmpFs(Collections.singletonMap("/testtmpfs", "rw"))
                .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(log))
                .withReuse(true)
                .withPrivilegedMode(true)
                .withConfigurationOverride("testcontainers/mysql")
                .withInitScript("testcontainers/mysql/init.sql")
                .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.getHostConfig().withMemory(memoryInBytes).withMemorySwap(memorySwapInBytes));
    }
```

---

**Trial 3#**

Added `.withEnv("TZ","UTC")` or `.withEnv("serverTimezone","UTC")`

This produced the same results too

---

Comment: I suspect that the mysql container is not running in expected time zone. Did you configure it yourself or did you use the docker-compose file generated by JHipster? Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971314/how-to-configure-time-zone-in-testcontainers-mysql

Comment: I didn't make any changes to what was generated by jhipster.  I have docker desktop running and ran "./mvnw clean verify" and can see that a testcontainer and a MySQL container were running.
I tried adding the init.sql with the timezone from the link you shared, but it creates multiple MySQL containers without closing any.

Comment: To add, I run the application locally `./mvnw` against a mysql image I run with the following command.

```docker run -p 3307:3306 --name=LocalDb -d mysql:8.0.28```

However, its the testcontainer that throws the errors for the HibernateTimeZoneIT integration tests.

Comment: OK, in integration tests, you use a different container than the one from docker compose, its timezone configuration is probably wrong or missing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971314/how-to-configure-time-zone-in-testcontainers-mysql

Comment: In TestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory, it works if you remove 'serverTimezone=UTC'.

Comment: Also, it works if you add 'preserveInstants=false' (and keep 'serverTimezone=UTC')

Comment: Issue raised here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/22874

Comment: @ctamister, your solutions worked perfectly for running the tests. Thank you for raising the issue.